# How to deploy sidecarless envoy in Istio using eBPF?

Tags: istio, envoyproxy, ebpf

I read this very interesting article that shows how to use sidecarless envoy:

https://events.istio.io/istiocon-2022/sessions/sidecarless-ebpf-envoy/

But it does not show any hands on as to how to deploy sidecarless envoy for Istio virtual services.

Any practical hello world example that shows how to deploy sidecarless envoy for Istio would really help!

Answer (score 4):

I believe Idit is **referring to [Cilium Service Mesh](https://isovalent.com/blog/post/cilium-service-mesh/)** when she talks of sidecarless service mesh with eBPF. You can find [how to deploy Cilium Service Mesh in the Cilium documentation](https://docs.cilium.io/en/stable/gettingstarted/#service-mesh).

Note that Cilium Service Mesh is an alternative to Istio Service Mesh, the latter relying on sidecar instances of Envoy. [Cilium also supports an integration with Istio](https://docs.cilium.io/en/stable/gettingstarted/istio/#gsg-istio) if you want to use Istio for the Service Mesh but Cilium as the underlying CNI.

Comment: There's a framework called merbridge which implements ebpf in istio. This video explains it https://youtu.be/r2wgInmsqsU  . But this doesn't give any hands on example for sidecarless envoy.

Comment: AFAIK, Merbridge doesn't remove the need for sidecars; it simply improves performance using BPF sockops. Cilium implements the same performance improvement under the `--sockops-enable` option. The author of BPF sockops in the kernel is also the author of the support in Cilium.